# How to make the application execute someting when i close it?

Tags: android

I want to know how to execute some code when I'm closing the application, this because I need to update a database I created, but only when the application is closed.

I hope u could help me.

Comment: What *precisely* do you mean by "the application is closed"? That does not really exist on Android, and so we need to understand what "the application is closed" means to you in order to provide you with advice.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: override onPause() or onStop() or onDestroy() - CommonsWare is right. it depends of what do you want to do

Comment: I mean that i want the application does an update on the DB when I close the application using the "recent application" of my device. I hope u understand better now.

Comment: I've tried to override the onStop() method, but it exec the code even if I put the app in the background. I want it to save only if I delete it from the recent application.

Comment: I don't know why but now it seems to work even with the onStop() method...

Answer (score 1):

onDestroy() and  onStop()is called once you app is destroyed.Check Activity [LifeCycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

You must use onPause() or onSaveInstanceState(Bundle).in some case onDestroy() and onStop() might not be called before killing app.